# Any Idea on on how does the HTML 5 Terminal work?

Tags: html

I happend to stumble upon this site

http://www.htmlfivewow.com/demos/terminal/terminal.html
It is simply amazing. I was just wondering on how is the terminal being emulated in the browser ?  Can we embed the terminal in the browser and use it normally ? If so how?

i found this link which kinda enlightens the architecture  http://www.htmlfivewow.com/slide33
But one thing aint clear what exactly is CRX-LEss Web app ? its completly new term , i havent herd of it before ( googling dint quite help me )

Answer (score 2):

The actual presentation for the demos is from the Google I/O conference, and the talk was called HTML5: The Wow and the How.  If you watch the video, they go over everything that's implemented in the terminal demo:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlwY6_W4VG8

It's very cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

A great thing about the web is that on any page you can View Source. Give it a shot. The source is well-structured and though it could be better-commented it's pretty straightforward. Even if you don't understand it in its entirety it will give you a place to start searching for the techniques used.

With JavaScript, the DOM, and `<canvas>` (which, I should mention, isn't used in this instance) just about anything can be created, from terminal emulators to Nintendo emulators.

Answer (score 0):

A CRX-Less web app is an unzipped Chrome extension and points to the `manifest.json` file for the extension. It is an experimental feature and must be enabled in the `chrome:flags` page. https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/no_crx explains how the process works.